# Place to set SQLite PRAGMA option in Django project

Tags: django, sqlite

According to [this test](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/sqlite-performance-and-django/), setting `PRAGMA synchronous=OFF` can dramatically improve SQLite write performance.

I am well aware of the drawbacks, but would still like to try this out.

**What would be the best location within a Django project to set this PRAGMA option?**

I cannot do it from `settings.py` - at least not the way the article suggests - because `from django.db import connection` would cause a recursive import error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this code in the `__init__.py` file of one of your installed app:

```
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created
def activate_foreign_keys(sender, connection, **kwargs):
    """Enable integrity constraint with sqlite."""
    if connection.vendor == 'sqlite':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;')

connection_created.connect(activate_foreign_keys)
```

Comment: Although I removed my DB file, removed all the previous migrations, and created new migrations, this made no difference for me.  The tables were not created with "on delete cascade" as expected.  I wonder why that's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

The article suggests that you add that as a middleware (at the very end). That middleware is then configured as a string inside settings.py, so you shouldn't get any import conflicts.

Comment: This is quite an old thread, but may I still point out that middlewares are called at each request, and therefore may not be the ideal place for sqlite pragmas like setting `synchronous`, since it feels more like a one-off decision.